# Rails: Passing nested attributes to vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, webpack

I have a Survey model

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And Quesiton model which is nested to "survey" as below;

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    enum qtype: [:multiple_choice, :check_boxes, :short_answer]
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And option model connected to question as nested.

```
 class Option < ApplicationRecord      
      belongs_to :question 
    end
```

Parameters in my `surveys_controller`:

```
def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes:[:id, :title, :qtype, :_destroy, options_attributes:[:id, :otext, _destroy]])
    end
```

It is working clear Without Vue.js implementing.
I want to use vue.js for making dynamic form. 
What should i do passing do form `all nested attributes` Without using '`gon`' gem
also which json file should i create with `jbuilder`?

Thanks

Comment: Using gon may be the easiest way. Have you looked at Vue on rails project? github.com/vueonrails

Comment: yes you are right but there is no sample works with nested attributes... :(